# python subprocess.readline() blocking when calling another python script

Tags: linux, python-2.7

I've been playing with using the subprocess module to run python scripts as sub-processes and have come accross a problem with reading output line by line.

The documentation I have read indicates that you should be able to use subprocess and call readline() on stdout, and this does indeed work if the script I am calling is a bash script. However when I run a python script readline() blocks until the whole script has completed.

I have written a couple of test scripts that repeat the problem. In the test scripts I attmept to run a python script (tst1.py) as a sub-process from within a python script (tst.py) and then read the output of tst1.py line by line.

tst.py starts tst1.py and tries to read the output line by line:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys, subprocess, multiprocessing, time
cmdStr = 'python ./tst1.py'
print(cmdStr)
cmdList = cmdStr.split()
subProc = subprocess.Popen(cmdList, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

while(1):
    # this call blocks until tst1.py has completed, then reads all the output
    # it then reads empty lines (seemingly for ever)
    ln = subProc.stdout.readline()
    if ln:
        print(ln)
```

tst1.py simply loops printing out a message:
    #!/usr/bin/env python
    import time

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    x = 0
    while(x<20):
        print("%d: sleeping ..." % x)
        # flushing stdout here fixes the problem
        #sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(1)
        x += 1
```

If tst1.py is written as a shell script tst1.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
x=0

while [ $x -lt 20 ]
do
    echo $x: sleeping ...
    sleep 1
    let x++
done
```

readline() works as expected.

After some playing about I discovered the situation can be resolved by flushing stdout in tst1.py, but I do not understand why this is required. I was wondering if anyone had an explanation for this behaviour ?

I am running redhat 4 linux:
Linux lb-cbga-05 2.6.9-89.ELsmp #1 SMP Mon Apr 20 10:33:05 EDT 2009 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 0):

Because if the output is buffered somewhere the parent process won't see it until the child process exists at that point the output is flushed and all fd's are closed. As for why it works with bash without *explicitly* flushing the output, because when you type `echo` in a most shells it actually forks a process that executes `echo` (which prints something) and exists so the output is flushed too.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I did not realise echo forked a separate process, hence my confusion that the bash script worked.Presumably this means that stdout, by default, is buffered by the child process. A quick google tells me that you can use expect unbuffer to get round this, though I have not yet tried this.

Comment: ... sorry accidently pressed return.